# How do I diagnose this POST 53 issue?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I have an Asrock X299 taichi motherboard that started misbehaving yesterday.

I was rebooting to update Windows, and the screen remained black. Initially it gave a GPU POST (Dr. Debug) error of `b7`, which then become a `53` error since I took out the GPU.

No matter what I try now, I get an error `53`. What's going on?

Here's what I tried:

- 1 have 4 RAM banks. I've tried to use only one at a time. I've tried to use none. I've tried to use all four.
- I've tried two different GPUs (both of which I am quite certain work)
- I've re-seated the CPU twice
- I've tried to reflash the BIOS pre-POST using the "BIOS flashback" feature but it fails
- I've disconnected the system, removed the CMOS battery, connected the reset CMOS pins and let it rest for a night.

The relevant hardware is:

- Ram DIMM DDR4 64GB Crucial Ballistix Sport LT Kit 16GBx4
- ASRock X299 Taichi Intel 2066 [90-MXB5C0-A0UAYZ]
- Intel 2066 i7-7820X 3,6GHz Skylake

Comment: Did your update process include a BIOS update? Are you able to flash the BIOS with latest?

Comment: The update process did not include a BIOS update afaict. I can't update the BIOS via the "BIOS flashback" feature. The mobo has 2 copies of the BIOS though, so perhaps it's possible to switch to the other version. I'm just not sure how to, though.

Comment: On the BIOS splash screen it should show you, but it's likely F9 or F12. My Gigabyte UEFI bios has a similar feature.

Comment: @spikey_richie there is no bios splash screen, the screen is blank